# How could I enter a runtime WHERE condition in a Oracle Forms12?

Tags: dynamic, runtime, where-clause, oracle12c, oracleforms

In Forms 6 runtime there was an option to enter a ':' in a text FIELD to bring up a prompt to enter a WHERE condition during runtime so users could enter anything they wanted.

After we upgraded from 6i to 12, the option do not have any effect in Forms12.

We would like know if something like that exists in Forms 12 runtime for dynamically entering a condition for `WHERE` clause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the configuration of you forms setup you've got a .env-file defined.
In this .env-file you have an option FORMS_RESTRICT_ENTER_QUERY, default this is set to TRUE so you can't enter any sql, but if you set this to FALSE you can:

```
# Disable/remove this variable if end-users need access to the query-where
# functionality which potentially allows them to enter arbitrary SQL
# statements when in enter-query mode.
#
FORMS_RESTRICT_ENTER_QUERY=FALSE
```